# Principal submatrix of a unitary matrix is unitary

Tags: matrices, unitary-matrices

On what condition a principle submatrix of a unitary matrix would be unitary itself?

As an example, let's say $T$ is 3x3 and unitary. Principle submatrix $S_{2x2}$ is created by removing the first row and first column of $T$. Is $S_{2x2}$ unitary in all conditions?

I am coming from an engineering background; I was wondering if there is an easy way to prove this mathematically for an $N*N$ matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost never unitary except in the trivial case that the original unitary matrix is (up to permutation) a block matrix. An easy way to see this is that the rows and columns of a unitary matrix must be orthonormal, so in particular must have norm $1$ as vectors, so the rows and columns of a principal submatrix will typically have norm less than $1$ because you're omitting entries of the corresponding vectors. They'll only have norm $1$ if all the omitted entries are $0$.

Comment: @Yuan thank you! What if we look at it the opposite way? Let's say we have a $4x4$ unitary matrix to be used as a block matrix in the center of a $\6times 6$ matrix. Could we populate the $6x6$ matrix with a non-trivial solution to be unitary?

Comment: Yes, you can take it to be a block matrix with a $4 \times 4$ unitary block and a $2 \times 2$ unitary block. The argument above says this is the only way to do it.

Comment: Great, thank you!